# Getting error "NameError: name 'base' is not defined" while trying to run a Deep Q Network in Google Collab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I'm using Google Collab to try run my code but I cant seem to fix this issue.
*Note: I have an Environment setup in Pycharm where this issue doesn't appear and the code runs (just very laggy due to intense training).*
Currently running on Tensorflow 2.0 and Python 3.7

```
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-14174aa69df8> in <module>()
    666 
    667     # Find Initial State
--> 668     cur_state = env.reset()
    669     dqn_agent = DQN(env, cur_state.shape)
    670     dqn_agent.save_model('models/deepq.h5')

4 frames
<ipython-input-5-14174aa69df8> in reset(self)
    303         self.car = Car(self.world, *self.track[0][1:4])
    304 
--> 305         return self.step(None)[0]
    306 
    307     def step(self, action):

<ipython-input-5-14174aa69df8> in step(self, action)
    319         self.t += 1.0 / FPS
    320 
--> 321         self.state = self.render("state_pixels")
    322 
    323         step_reward = 0

<ipython-input-5-14174aa69df8> in render(self, mode)
    340         assert mode in ['human', 'state_pixels', 'rgb_array']
    341         if self.viewer is None:
--> 342             from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
    343             self.viewer = rendering.Viewer(WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H)
    344             self.score_label = pyglet.text.Label('0000', font_size=36,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 try:
---> 27     from pyglet.gl import *
     28 except ImportError as e:
     29     raise ImportError('''

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py in <module>()
    223 elif compat_platform == 'darwin':
    224     from .cocoa import CocoaConfig as Config
--> 225 del base  # noqa: F821
    226 
    227 # XXX remove

NameError: name 'base' is not defined
```

Link to the code - https://github.com/eoinmca/Final_Year_Project/blob/master/google_collab_version.py

If anyone tries to reproduce this error you need to ensure collab is running tf2 not tf1

Prerequisites to set up collab

```
!pip install box2d-py
!pip install gym[Box_2D]

print(tf.__version__)
# Run next lines if not on tf2
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```